# How to use lambda if else in map() on list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I have a list `['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']`

I want to run map on it which will select a few items

```
l = map(lambda x : x if x == "apple" else pass, ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'])
```

it seems that it should work but its giving syntax error

What is the issue here?

Comment: What do you expect to happen on the ``pass`` branch? Note that ``map`` converts *every* input element to an output element. It cannot remove elements.

Comment: My usual reminder: If you need a `lambda` to use `map` or `filter`, don't. It'll be slower and less readable than an equivalent list comprehension/generator expression that avoids a `lambda` by inlining the same logic.

Comment: @ShadowRanger can you give me an example?

Comment: @rahulKushwaha: Example of what? Your answers already show the options (`map`/`filter`, listcomp, genexpr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `filter` here and use `lambda x : x == "apple"`.

**Ex:**

```
l = list(filter(lambda x : x == "apple", ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']))
print(l)
```

Comment: or a list comprehension: `l = [x for x in input if predicate(x)]`

Answer (score 2):

you need this:

```
[x for x in ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'] if x == "apple"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is not a value, so you can't use it in an expression. You could use `None`, but then you end up with `['apple', None, None]` rather than just `['apple']`, so you have to filter the `None`s like this:

```
l = filter(lambda x: x is not None, map(lambda x : x if x == "apple" else None, ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']))
```

A cleaner solution would be to use list comprehension:

```
l = [ x for x in ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'] if x == 'apple' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on size of your `list` it might be better to use `generator` rather than `list` comprehension, that is:

```
l = (x for x in ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'] if x=='apple')
```

generally `list` comprehensions will lead to bigger memory usage, than equivalent generators, though for small sizes difference might be neglible.

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to use `pass` keyword in conditional expressions(ternary operator)

you can read more about conditional expressions in [PEP308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)

So, if you want to use the `map` built-in function you have to pick an `"else"` value for the ternary operator, ex:

```
map(lambda x : x if x == "apple" else None, ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'])
```

or if you want to filter your list by the string "apple" you can use @Rakesh suggested solution by using the built-in function `filter`:

```
list(filter(lambda x : x == "apple", ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']))
```